# Unpacking cells containing list of lists in Pandas DataFrame into separate rows and columns of a new DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the DataFrame `df`:

```
    a  b                   c
0   7  5  [[-4, 7], [-5, 6]]
1  13  5  [[-9, 4], [-3, 7]]
```

I want to flatten the column with list of lists cells (column 'c') into a separate DataFrame such that:

1. The separate lists correspond to individual entries
2. The elements of the separate lists are split into new columns

I manage to obtain the desired result below (I understand there has been an `int` to `float` conversion, but this is not a bother for me):

```
    a  b    d    e
0   7  5 -4.0  7.0
1   7  5 -5.0  6.0
2  13  5 -9.0  4.0
3  13  5 -3.0  7.0
```

However, I believe the way I do it is not ideal since it firstly uses a lot of code, and secondly uses `iterrows()`.

Below is my code:

```
old_cols = list(df)
old_cols.remove('c')
new_cols = ['d', 'e']
all_cols = old_cols + new_cols
df_flat = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_cols)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    data = row['c']
    for entry in data:
        temp_series = pd.Series(index=new_cols)
        temp_series['d'] = entry[0]
        temp_series['e'] = entry[1]
        new_row = pd.concat([row[old_cols], temp_series])
        df_flat = df_flat.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) :

```
df = df.groupby(['a','b'])\
       .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['c'].tolist()[0], columns=['c','d']))\
       .reset_index([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
    a  b  c  d
0   7  5 -4  7
1   7  5 -5  6
2  13  5 -9  4
3  13  5 -3  7
```

**Explanation :**

Since for each value in column `c` are list of lists. To upack them and to make them different columns we taking `x['c'].tolist()` this contains 2 open and close brackets (`[[[values],[values]]]`) which not useful, so `x['c'].tolist()[0]` gives `[[values],[values]]` which is used as data to `pd.DataFrame` with columns `['c','d']` and finaly `reset_index` on `levels = [0,1]` which are columns `['a','b']`.

```
print(pd.DataFrame([[-4, 7], [-5, 6]],columns=['c','d']))
   c  d
0 -4  7
1 -5  6

print(df.groupby(['a','b'])\
        .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['c'].tolist()[0], columns=['c','d'])))
        c  d
a  b        
7  5 0 -4  7
     1 -5  6
13 5 0 -9  4
     1 -3  7
```

Comment: little explanation will surely help to understand more :-)